# Cannot resolve symbol 'app.image.tag' error for spring boot maven project

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven

I was trying to add Docker Image Configuration to my pom.xml file but i am getting **Cannot resolve symbol 'app.image.tag'** error while trying to add the `${app.image.tag}` to the `<image></image>` tag.

Here is the code:

```
<executions>
   <execution>
     <id>push-custom-tag</id>
     <configuration>
       <to>
         <image>docker.io/vikinglsord98/${app.image.name}:${app.image.tag}</image>
       </to>
     </configuration>
     <goals>
       <goal>build</goal>
     </goals>
 </execution>
```

I have tried searching online but couldn't find anything relating to this error for Spring Boot.